# In C# with CSOM, How can I copy a file from a known location to a known Folder?

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom, folder, copy

I have one function which uses `SearchExecutor` finds to find the path of a specified file, which returns a string like.

> https://example.sharepoint.com/sites/DevelopementTestingSite/Shared Documents/Forms/DispForm.aspx?ID=43

I have another function which creates and returns a `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Folder`.

Give:

1. The filename,
2. The file location, and
3. The Folder.

How can I copy the file to the folder?

If it helps, the ServerRelativePath has been initialized on the Folder with:

```
            Folder itemFolder = folderItem.Folder;
            context.Load(itemFolder, folder => folder.ServerRelativePath);
            context.ExecuteQuery();
            return itemFolder;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the string `https://example.sharepoint.com/sites/DevelopementTestingSite/Shared Documents/Forms/DispForm.aspx?ID=43`, you could get the file by the id. Then copy to the folder.

My test demo code :

```
        Web web = ctx.Web;
        List list = web.GetListByTitle("Documents");
       // ctx.Load(list);
        //ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        ListItem item = list.GetItemById(2);
        File file = item.File;
        ctx.Load(file);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        item.File.CopyTo("/sites/test/Shared%20Documents/folder1/"+item.File.Name, true);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: cheers for the info.  I'm trying to play with it currently.  Do I correctly understand that I can disregard most of the file location other than the id, as long as I access the "Documents" List?

Comment: Yes. You only need to use the listname and the id, that will be enough.